# ring homomorphism and cardinality

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

suppose $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field and $(R,\oplus,*) $ is a ring then there is no ring homomorphism from $F$ to $R$ when $|F|>|R|$

(here all rings assumed commutative and non zero i.e multiplicative identity is different from additive identity)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am not proving it completely but here are the propositions(which you can prove yourself) with which the given statement can be claimed.

s0: $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field and $(R,\oplus,*) $ with ring homorphism $\phi: F \rightarrow R$

p1: Fields has only nontrivial ideals.

p2: If $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism then $Ker(\psi)$ is Ideal of a domain ring.

p3: If $\psi:R_1 \rightarrow R_2$ is a ring homomorphism then $Ker(\psi) \neq R_1 $.

now from s0, p1, p2, and p3;

s4: $Ker(\phi)=\{0\}$ for s0

p5: if $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism and $Ker(\psi)=\{0\}$ then $\psi$ is injection.

p6: if $\psi: A \rightarrow B $ is injection then $|A|\leq|B|$.

now from s4, p5 and p6,

s7: $|F|\leq|R|$ for s0.

done.

Here s is used for statement and p is used for the proposition.